# why a double implementation of reducer method returns NAN when trying to find the second larger number in a number array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So, I did this in order to find the second biggest value in an array (I know there are a lot of answers out there, I just want to know why this approach fails)

With a first `reduce()` method on the number array I find the largest number, then using a second `reduce()` method I tried to use an `if` statement to check return the biggest number only if the compared numbers are not the previous biggest one found. This is the code:

```
const arr = [1,6,2,7,3,9,5,8];

const biggest = arr.reduce((a,b)=> {
  return Math.max(a,b)
})

console.log(biggest)

const secondBiggest = arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
  if(a!= biggest && b!= biggest){
    return Math.max(a,b)
  }
})

console.log(secondBiggest) // --> NAN
```

Comment: Check this with a debugger. Then answer this simple question - what happens when the `if` condition is `false`? What is `a` in the *next* iteration? What happens if you plug in that value to `Math.max`?

Comment: You could do it without reduce btw. `Math.max(...arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration you need to return something from `reduce` function. so currently you just return when `(a!= biggest && b!= biggest)` is true. so you need to return the original value of accumulator `a` when the condition doesn't match as well (`return a`).

Learn more about [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [1,6,2,7,3,9,5,8];

const biggest = arr.reduce((a,b)=> {
  return Math.max(a,b)
})

console.log(biggest)

const secondBiggest = arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
  if(a!= biggest && b!= biggest){
    return Math.max(a,b)
  }
  return a; // if you don't return anything during the next iteration the accumulator will have `undefined`.  
})

console.log(secondBiggest) // --> NAN
```

Comment: This won't work if the second biggest number will be before `9` instead of after

Comment: fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You want return your accumulator as is if the current one is the biggest

```js
const arr = [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 9, 5, 2];

const biggest = Math.max([...arr])

console.log(biggest)

const secondBiggest = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (current != biggest) {
    return Math.max(accumulator, b)
  }
  return a
})

console.log(secondBiggest)
```